# react.js deleting one of few rendered components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

Here is my first post.
I am in processs of creating todo app. 
My app is adding new task to task list when plus button is clicked , and after few clicks u got few task simple , but the problem is that each task got delete Icon , which unfortunately by my lack of sufficient skills is deleting all components instead of the one , which icon belongs to.

Here is App.js code

```
class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.handleDelete = this.handleDelete.bind(this);
    this.addTask = this.addTask.bind(this);
    this.state = {taskNum: 0,
                  delete: false            
    }
}
addTask(){
    this.setState({
        taskNum: this.state.taskNum +1,
        delete:false
    });
}
handleDelete(e){
    console.log(e.target);
    this.setState({delete: true});
}
render() {
    const tasks = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.taskNum; i += 1) {
        tasks.push(!this.state.delete && <Task key={i} number={i} deleteTask={this.handleDelete}/>);
      };

  return (
    <div className="ui container content">
        <h2 className="centerHeader header">TODO LIST</h2>
        <h3 className="taskheader secondaryHeader">Tasks <Icon className="addNew plus" action={this.addTask}/></h3>
        <div className="ui container five column grid taskList">
            {tasks}
        </div> ...
```

and here is Task.js

```
export class Task extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.dataChanged = this.dataChanged.bind(this);
    this.state ={message: 'TASK' + (this.props.number+1),
                }
    }
    customValidateText(text) {
      return (text.length > 0 && text.length < 31);
    }
    dataChanged(data) {
      console.log(data.message);
       this.setState({message: data.message});
    }
    render(){
    const centerRow = classNames('textCenter', 'row');
    return (<div className="ui column task">
                  <div className={centerRow}><InlineEdit
              validate={this.customValidateText}
              activeClassName="editing"
              text={this.state.message}
              paramName="message"
              change={this.dataChanged}
              style={{
                background: 'inherit',
                textAlign:'center',
                maxWidth: '100%' ,
                display: 'inline-block',
                margin: 0,
                padding: 0,
                fontSize: '1em',
                outline: 0,
                border: 0
              }}
            /></div>
                  <div className={centerRow}><Icon className="browser outline huge center"/> </div>
                  <div className={centerRow}><Icon className="large maximize"/><Icon className="large save saveTask"/><Icon className="large trash outline" action={this.props.deleteTask} /></div>
          </div>
          );
```

I thought of trying to e.target and select the parentNode but i am not sure if thats the proper solution since using react , so could u help me find efficient solution for this problem so that when trash icon is clicked it will delete only parent component.

Comment: What's `delete` in the App state supposed to mean? Didn't you mean to put it to the Task state (to mark the particular task as deleted)?

Comment: yeah that what i meant

Answer (score 0):

One of the main reasons why react is powerful is that it give you the ability to maintain your DOM based on you data without having to do any manipulation to the DOM by yourself

So for your example to be more React JS friendly you need to do some changes, that will also fix your problem

1- You need to keep an actual state of your data, so adding a todo item means an actual real data added to your program, not just a component representation.

2- Removing a task represented by a `component` means removing the data it self, so deleting one of the tasks means deleting its actual data, and then react will handle updating the DOM for you, so the idea of a flag to hide a component is not React JS way

3- The way react knows when to render and how to handle all your data is managed by the component `state` .. so you save your data in component `state` and you only need to care about updating the `state`, then react will know that it will need to render again but now with the new updated list of tasks

I did some changes in your code with commented lines explaining why

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.handleDelete = this.handleDelete.bind(this);
        this.addTask = this.addTask.bind(this);
        this.state = {
                tasks: [  ], // this is the array that will hold the actual data and based on its content react will handle rendering the correct data
                counter : 1  // this counter is incremented every task addition just to make sure we are adding different task name just for the example explanation
            }
        }
    }

    addTask(){
        this.setState({
            tasks: this.state.tasks.push( "TASK" + counter); //This how we add a new task as i said you are adding an actual task data to the state
            counter : this.state.counter + 1 //increment counter to have different task name for the next addition
        });
    }

    //i changed this function to accept the task name so when you click delete it will call this function with task name as parameter
    //then we use this task name to actually remove it from the tasks list data in our state
    handleDelete(taskToDelete){

        this.setState({
            //the filter function below will remove the task from the array in our state
            //After this state update, react will render the component again but now with the tasks list after removing deleting this one
            tasks : this.state.tasks.filter((task) => {
                if(task != taskToDelete)
                    return word;
            })
        });
    }

    render() {
        const tasks = [];
        //Notice here we pass an actual data to every Task component so i am adding prop message to take the value from this.state.tasks[index]
        for (let i=0 ; i< this.state.tasks.length ; i++)
        {
            tasks.push(<Task key={i} message={this.state.tasks[i]} deleteTask={this.handleDelete}/>);
        }
        

      return (
        <div className="ui container content">
            <h2 className="centerHeader header">TODO LIST</h2>
            <h3 className="taskheader secondaryHeader">Tasks <Icon className="addNew plus" action={this.addTask}/></h3>
            <div className="ui container five column grid taskList">
                {tasks}
            </div> ...
            )
    }
}
```

Task Component

```
export class Task extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.dataChanged = this.dataChanged.bind(this);
        this.removeCurrentTask = this.removeCurrentTask.bind(this);
        //Here i am setting the state from the passed prop message
        this.state ={
            message: this.props.message
        }
    }

    customValidateText(text) {
      return (text.length > 0 && text.length < 31);
    }

    dataChanged(data) {
       console.log(data.message);
       this.setState({message: data.message});
    }

    removeCurrentTask (){
        //calling the deleteTask function with the current task name.
        this.props.deleteTask(this.state.message);
    }

    render(){
        const centerRow = classNames('textCenter', 'row');
        return (
            <div className="ui column task">
                <div className={centerRow}><InlineEdit
                      validate={this.customValidateText}
                      activeClassName="editing"
                      text={this.state.message}
                      paramName="message"
                      change={this.dataChanged}
                      style={{
                        background: 'inherit',
                        textAlign:'center',
                        maxWidth: '100%' ,
                        display: 'inline-block',
                        margin: 0,
                        padding: 0,
                        fontSize: '1em',
                        outline: 0,
                        border: 0
                      }}
                    /></div>
                <div className={centerRow}><Icon className="browser outline huge center"/> </div>
                //Notice the action handler here is changed to use removeCurrentTask defined in current component 
                //BTW i don't know how Icon is handling the action property ... but now you can simply use onClick and call removeCurrentTask 
                <div className={centerRow}><Icon className="large maximize"/><Icon className="large save saveTask"/><Icon className="large trash outline" action={this.removeCurrentTask} /></div>
            </div>
              );
    }
}
```

Comment: you are welcome ... i also edited the answer with all changes that needs to be done in your code with commented lines to explain why they are done like that ... i hope this will help you understand it more

Comment: Now you helped a lot I will try to implement it soon :)